# controller.setview is not a function error

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

I have recently migrated my ExtJS4.2 application to ExtJS5.1.
I have followed these steps to migrate:  1) Created new application with ExtJS5.1 gpl version using ExtJS Sencha Cmd6.0.

2) Copied the app\model,app\controller,app\store to 5.1 application
3) Copied Persons.js view file to ExtJS5.1\app\view\main folder and added it  as xtype in Main.js
4) When i run the application, i could see error:
Uncaught TypeError: controller.setView is not a function
It is happening in applyController function of ext-all-rtl-debug.js

Can anyone help me to resolve this?

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a view but did not create view model and view controller for it. Due to that i got the error. Once i created view model the problem got resolved. This is the new change from ExtJS4 to ExtJS5.  When we create a view we need to create ViewModel for it.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, because I was stupid enough to extend from Ext.app.Controller instead of Ext.app.ViewController in which case you have the same issue.....